# Creating a Unity-Like DrawableObject in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotation, matrix-multiplication

So, I am trying to create a class in OpenGL that will make objects very easy to create, delete and orient. The interface would have the standard functions move(), translate(), rotate(), scale(), but also has a few methods related to parenting. I want an object to be able to set a joint to its parent and rotate, scale and transform along with its parents. This would allow me to create essentially a human skeleton from smaller components.

Assuming I have the vertex drawing working (which I do), but I am having a little bit of trouble constructing the MVP for the model here was my thought process. If I just knew how to combine rotation matrices I would be okay.. but I don't think that's possible without quaternions. Anyone know of how to fix or a better way to solve it?

```
glm::vec3 scaling;  //Scale x, y, z
glm::vec3 rotation; //Rotation x, y, z
glm::vec3 position; //Position x, y, z
glm::vec3 offset;   //Offset of the connection between the parent and this
Drawable* parent;   //Parent connection joint
std::set<Drawable* const> children; //All child connections

inline glm::mat4 getModelMatrixCopy() const
{
    glm::mat4 mm(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 s(1.0f);

    s = glm::scale(s, scaling);
    mm = glm::translate(mm, position);
    mm = glm::rotate(mm, glm::radians(rotation.x), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0f));
    mm = glm::rotate(mm, glm::radians(rotation.y), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0f));
    mm = glm::rotate(mm, glm::radians(rotation.z), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0f));

    return mm * s;
}

inline void translate(float x, float y, float z)
{
    position.x += x;
    position.y += y;
    position.z += z;

    for (auto it = children.begin(); it != children.end(); it++)
    {
        (*it)->translate(x, y, z);
    }
}

inline void move(float x, float y, float z)
{
    for (auto it = children.begin(); it != children.end(); it++)
    {
        auto child = (*it);
        float xOffset = (position.x - child->position.x);
        float yOffset = (position.y - child->position.y);
        float zOffset = (position.z - child->position.z);
        child->move(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, z + zOffset);
    }

    position.x = x;
    position.y = y;
    position.z = z;
}

inline void rotate(float xDeg, float yDeg, float zDeg)
{
    //???? This just seems wrong, need to rotate based on the addition of all previous children

    rotation.x += xDeg;
    rotation.y += yDeg;
    rotation.z += zDeg;

    for (auto it = children.begin(); it != children.end(); it++)
    {
        auto child = (*it);
        child->rotate(xDeg, yDeg, zDeg);
    }
}

inline void scale(float x, float y, float z)
{
    scaling.x *= x;
    scaling.y *= y;
    scaling.z *= z;

    for (auto it = children.begin(); it != children.end(); it++)
    {
        auto child = (*it);
        child->offset.x *= x;
        child->offset.y *= y;
        child->offset.z *= z;
        child->scale(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quaternions are the way to go imho. They are elegant and efficient. The only other way I could think of would be to keep track of all rotations and their order. That would be tidious... Quaternions you can simple multiply together, give it a try, you won't regret it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am technically allowed to use quaternions sadly. Its for an assignment that wasn't required to be OOP, but I wanted to for future designs. But i agree with you!